# Apache Mamp won't start?

Tags: macos, apache, mamp, osx-elcapitan

From the GUI it won't start and from the terminal. Won't start even if i just try to start the normal apache server that comes with OSX

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl: line 80: 30016 Trace/BPT trap: 5       $HTTPD -k $ARGV
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saw this when mySQL was still running. Sometimes it will not start at all. Restarting the Mac cured the problem for me (always).

OSX 10.11

Greetings,

Peter